# Android 7.0 : Custom notification sound not working anymore

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, my code was working perfectly 1 month ago. But now my custom sound does not play at all.

**My device** : Mi note 4

**Android version** 7.0 NRD90M

I have spent entire day searching on the internet but could not find any working solution. Is there any update regarding my issue ?

**Payload**

```
{body={"notification_type":"","booking_id":"","booking_no_text":"","guest_mobile":"","ride_date":"","guest_name":"","pickup_longitude":"","reporting_time":"","fyear":"","pickup_latitude":"","pickup_address":""}, icon=, sound=, title=Booking Notification}
```

**Notification builder**

```
final Intent service = new Intent(this, MessagingService.class);
            service.putExtra("msg", "New Trip Request");
            startService(service);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(msg_content)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(sound)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 0000, 0000, 500, 000});

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                mBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorPrimary));
            } else {
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }

            NotificationManager mnNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                String channelId = mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, title, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                mnNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
            }

            mnNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

            stopService(service);
```

Earlier the sound was playing perfectly. But suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Have you noticed any log while execution of this code?

Comment: @RutvikBhatt 
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found. **and** 
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after 2 days of frustration. If you are using MI phone and have recently updated your UI. Then all you have to do is enable sound of your app in settings

**Goto** : Settings > Notifications & Status Bar > App Notifications > Select App and Enable Sound.

**Reference link :** https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/906p09/notification_sounds_not_working_on_miui_10_8719/

Comment: This is not right way. When first time users how they will know?